# React always returns index.html as response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set up a datatable in my react app and I'd like to do the following

Here's how the documentation for the datatable is doing it:

```
<script src="plugins/table/datatable/datatables.js"></script>
<script>
        $('#dt').DataTable({ 
            "stripeClasses": [],
            "pageLength": 7 
        });
    </script>
```

I tried doing it in react via

```
import ../plugins/table/datatable/datatables.js"
```

I also used the method, where you create a script element and append in to the document.body, but both methods seem to return the index.html of my app.

I've read that it's due to React's way of handling requests - I've done an API and I can successfully hit it, however I'm not familiar how to import local files sucessfully. I've also tried importing the files inside the index.html file, but the result is still the same.